# Add new Folder and its components

Tags: git

im having a problem where my git repository have folders and inside the folder there are files and other folders as well. But when i add a new folder with some files in it it does not show when i do a `git status` and theres nothing to add nor commit too.

So how to I put my new folder and the file in it in the staging directory or the working directory?

like:

- `myFolder/file.txt` --> committed
- `myFolder/myFolder2/someFile.txt` --> committed
- `myFolder/images/sampleImage.jpg` --> it does not show as untracked or when I do `git status`. I need to include this in the repository. Or I need to track this.

Comment: Are any files in myFolder/images tracked by Git? If not, git won't list myFolder/images/sampleImage.jpg as untracked, only myFolder/images. Is there anything in your .gitignore or .git/info/exclude files that might match the files in question? What's the output of `git ls-files -o`? How about `git ls-files -i`?

Comment: myFolder is tracked but the myFolder/images directory is a new folder which is untracked that i've added recently and also the sampleImage.jpg...and there nothing in .gitignore that excludes this particular file in the repo.. the `git ls-files -o` does not return anything and `git ls-files -i` returns `fatal:ls-files --ignored needs some exclude pattern`

Comment: @rockStar, if you do `git add myFolder/images/`, everything inside the folder will be added. Alternatively, if you do `git add myFolder/images/sampleImage.jpg`, that file will be added and other files in the directory will now show up as untracked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your new folder and files that you want to add don't match anything in your `.gitignore` file, then try `git add -A myFolder/images`. If the images folder has anything in it that isn't being ignored, that should force it to be staged.